# Is It Possible to Have Quartic Equation that Has Always Rational Root?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quartics

Let take the quartic equation $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e=0$, how can we find/construct $a, b, c, d,e$ such that root $x$ is always a rational number? i.e. a general condition on $a, b, c, d, e$ such that all the roots of the equation are rational.

We can use rational root theorem but that depends on root, I would like to find independent of the root, I don't need to have the root but the confirmation that the root is always rational.

For example  it might look like  $ax^4+(b+2a)x^3+(c+d)/2 \times x^2+dx+e$, in general,  $a, b, c, d,e$ could be expressed in some  rational variables and be true for any arbitrary values.

Comment: For example, $a+b+c+d+e=0$. If so, the equation has a root $1$.

Comment: In that same vein, if $e = 0$ the equation always has $0$ as a root; not that this solves OP's question, but it would be interesting if something like OP asks actually exists

Comment: It's very unclear to me exactly what you're asking. Do you want to know a _general_ condition on a/b/c/d/e such that _all_ the roots of the equation are rational?

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes.

Comment: The coefficients of the polynomial are functions of its roots; just write $Q(x)=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)$ and expand out the terms to see this. You could write $r_1=\frac{p_1}{q_1}$, etc., multiply the whole thing by $q_1q_2q_3q_4$ and find a 'general form'; I don't know how useful you'll find it, though...

Comment: Er, do you mean one or all roots rational ?

Comment: Do you allow Gaussian rationals ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust all roots. real rational

Comment: Beware that constructing the polynomials and expressing a general condition are two very different things.

Answer (score 2):

Let

$r_1, r_2, r_3, r_4 \in \Bbb Q; \tag 1$

then set

$f(x) = (x - r_1)(x - r_2)(x - r_3)(x - r_4)$
$= x^4 - (r_1 + r_2 + r_3 + r_4)x^3 + (r_1 r_2 + r_1 r_3 + r_1 r_4 + r_2 r_3 + r_2 r_4 + r_3 r_4)x^2$
$- (r_1 r_2 r_3 + r_1 r_2 r_4 + r_2 r_3 r_4) x + r_1 r_2 r_3 r_4; \tag 2$

finally, for any

$\rho \in \Bbb R \tag 3$

we take

$a = \rho, \tag 4$

$b = -\rho(r_1 + r_2 + r_3 + r_4), \tag 5$

$c = \rho(r_1 r_2 + r_1 r_3 + r_1 r_4 + r_2 r_3 + r_2 r_4 + r_3 r_4), \tag 6$

$d = -\rho(r_1 r_2 r_3 + r_1 r_2 r_4 + r_2 r_3 r_4), \tag 7$

$e = \rho r_1 r_2 r_3 r_4; \tag 8$

then the quartic polynmial

$p(x) = \rho f(x) = ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e \in \Bbb R[x] \tag 9$

has zeroes preciely as in (1).  Indeed, every real quartic with roots (1) takes  this form, since it must be divisible by $f(x)$ with quotient of degree 0, that is, a real number.

Comment: You can avoid the recourse to the parameter $\rho$ by specifying the ratios $b/a, c/a, d/a, e/a$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust:  yes, of course, but the OP seemed to want $a$ explicitly, so . . .

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are formulas for finding the roots of a general quartic $ax^4 + bx^3 + cx^2 + dx + e$ in [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#General_formula_for_roots); you can play with those to find some conditions to ensure the quartic will have some rational root.

Comment: That will be a ***lot*** of work!  But ***+1*** anyway.

Comment: The condition is easy to say, u have to remove square root, but it is hard to do, .....not a help

Comment: Well, I was thinking of something like 'what conditions make the square roots disappear?' in the formulas, or something like that

Comment: ... Yeah, now I see that it would take some work; but I couldn't find something simpler

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the easiest way to *generate* those polynomials is to choose four rationals (in increasing order $r_1< r_2< r_3< r_4$ for uniqueness), and to expand

$$(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4).$$